# Routine as argument -- generic variables not working

Tags: perl

I am working on writing a gaming system (wargames, etc.) and am creating the system for creating and displaying hex maps.  I realized quickly that I am repeatedly doing a nested loop of x=(0..maxx) and y=(0..maxy).  So I attempted to adapt some code I found somewhere (one of the advanced perl books, I forget where) to create an easier way to do this sort of looping thing.  This is what I came up with:

```
sub fillmap (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    no strict 'refs';
    use vars qw($x $y);
    my $caller = caller;
    local(*{$caller."::x"}) = \my $x;
    local(*{$caller."::y"}) = \my $y;
    foreach $x (0..5) {
        foreach $y (0..3) {
            warn "fillmap $x,$y\n";
            &{$code}($x,$y);
        }
    }
}
```

It's suppose to work like `sort`, but using `$x` and `$y` instead of `$a` and `$b`.

Note: the warn statement is for debugging.  I also simplified the x and y ranges (the array passed in determines the maxx and maxy values, but I didn't want to muddy this discussion with the routines for calculating them... I just hard-coded them to maxx=5 and maxy=3)

So, this execution of this routine like so:

```
fillmap {warn "$x,$y\n";} @map;
```

should yield a list of the x,y pairs.  But instead, it gives me this:

```
fillmap 0,0
,
fillmap 0,1
,
fillmap 0,2
,
fillmap 0,3
,
fillmap 1,0
,
...
```

Note, the "fillmap" lines are from the subroutine for debugging.  But instead of each x,y pair, I just get the comma ($x and $y are undefined).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `for $x` does its own localisation. The `$x` inside the loop isn't the `$x` that's aliased to `$caller::x`.

You need to do one of the following:

- Copy `$x` into `$caller::x` inside the loop.
- Alias `$caller::x` to `$x` inside the loop.

The following does the latter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub fillmap(&@) {
    my $code = shift;

    my $caller = caller();
    my $xp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{$caller.'::x'} };  local *$xp;
    my $yp = do { no strict 'refs'; \*{$caller.'::y'} };  local *$yp;

    for my $x (0..1) {
        *$xp = \$x;
        for my $y (0..2) {
            *$yp = \$y;
            $code->();
        }
    }
}


our ($x, $y);
fillmap { warn "$x,$y\n"; } '...';
```

You could avoid the need for `our ($x, $y);` by using `$a` and `$b` instead of `$x` and `$y`. You can't solve the problem by moving it (or `use vars qw( $x $y );`) into `fillmap` because you obviously intend `fillmap` to be used in a different package and lexical scope than the caller.

Comment: (I used `$caller::x` as a shorthand for `${caller().'::x'}` in the non-code parts. It won't do the right thing if used literally.)

Comment: `fillmap(&@)` should probably be `fillmap(&\@)`

Comment: It redundant to set `$caller::x` and pass `$x` as an argument. I undid one.

Comment: I would love some additional explanation on your solution... it works like a champ, but copying-n-pasting your code doesn't teach me much  :-)

Comment: Which part? The only element I added is that I changed `*caller::x = \$x;` to `*{\*caller::x} = \$x;` so I could split it into two statements (`$xp = \*$caller::x; *$xp = \$x;`). That's simply a reference-deference, just like `@{\@a}` is the same as `@a`.

Comment: The only other difference is that I moved the assignment to the glob into the loop, just like I said right above the code.

Comment: (oops, the `$` shouldn't be there in the RHS of the `$xp` assignment, two comments up)